# How to modify and write to file before printing to STDERR

Tags: shell, io-redirection, control-flow

I am working on an automated pull request check via GitHub actions and I want to preserve some data from a command's `stderr` output between jobs.

For this, I need to write the `stderr` to an *artifact* file, but before that I need to also remove some control chars from it via `sed`, otherwise I end up with something like:

```
\x1b[31mFound 344 errors!\x1b[39;49m
```

I then want the main command to return the same exit code in order to fail the check and prevent merging of the pull request.

I can probably take care of a subset of what needs doing, but am unable to take care of all 3 together together (sed > file write > stderr). If it makes it easier, I am okay with writing both `stdout` and `stderr` to the file as well.

Open to suggestions to do this differently.

Comment: Are those color/attribute codes? Normally there is an option to disable them in the command that generates them.

Comment: Please show us a minimal reproducible example of your script that we can use to test any solutions.

Comment: @Quasímodo indeed, they are. The command I'm referring to comes from another project so it's out of my control.

Comment: @terdon So far I am able to ensure that both streams get copied to a file as well as be displayed on terminal via `tee`: `somecommand 2&>1 | tee ./artifact.txt`. However, doing so loses the original exit status.

Comment: @terdon pardon me. I did not know about the `pipefail` shell option which essentially solves my problem. The final command being:
`set -o pipefail ; somecommand 2&>1 | tee ./artifact.txt` ; set +o pipefail`

Comment: @AbhishekJain I'm sorry but I simply have no idea what you mean since you haven't shown us any code to demonstrate the issue. As I said before, please [edit] your question and add a small example that reproduces the problem, and explain how you would want that example to work.

Comment: Yes, minimal example would be really useful now.

Comment: Apologies for not being able to provide a minimal repro-able code, mainly because there is none. I am trying to construct a command from scratch based on my requirements.

Fortunately I have been able to (mostly) solve it. Hopefully, the answer I posted will bring more context to you guys :)

Comment: It seems like a XY problem, as your sample output hints that you want to remove the color control characters of a `git` output thgough a `sed`, which indicates that you use a specific configuration for that characters to survive a pipe pass (like color "always" and not just "auto").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it using a combination of shell redirection operators, the [`tee`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) utility and [`pipefail`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) shell option:

**`set -o pipefail; somecommand 2&>1 | tee ./artifact.txt; set +o pipefail`**

Basically this:

1. sets the pipeline's return status as the value of the last command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.
2. duplicates the `stderr` from `stdout` with [`2&>1`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07) (or its shorthand `|&`) which is then passed as `stdin` to `tee` with the
3. invokes `tee` which copies its `stdin` to `stdout` while making a copy in `artifact.txt`.
4. restores the original pipe setting.

I had to live with both `stdout` and `stderr` being copied to the file because, apparently, Bash has no shorthand syntax that allows piping only `stderr` to a second command.

---

Other refs:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/731237
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/444013

Comment: The question is about filtering the stderr of a process through another command . All you do here is to write both stdout and stderr into the terminal and the file. Also I don't see the reason you set pipefail here.

Comment: For correctness you should run this in a subshell (surround it in parentheses) rather than executing `set +o pipefail` at the end, since you don't know the original value.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` you can run:

```
$ somecommand 2>&1 | tee ./artifact.txt;echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

And get the exit codes all along the pipe.

Comment: The exit status of this pipeline will be that of the last command. It will lose the exit status of `somecommand`.

Comment: Please do check the last command `echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"` show the array of all the exit codes in the pipe.

Comment: I don't want to show the exit codes, I, _basically_, want the entire thing to return the exit code of `somecommand`.

Comment: Of course can do whatever you want with ${PIPESTATUS[@]} We haven't seen a minimal example of what you wan to do, so I added the code to print them, you can obviously do whatever you want with it, including using the first element of the array to do an 'exit`. You really have to provide code if you expect people to tailor their answers to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I am an amateur at shell scripting so apologies for not framing the question properly .